# When SVG is generated as PDF text is indented but rest of drawing isn't

Tags: pdf, svg

We have template SVG drawings which have tags on the drawing to be replaced by text when the drawing is generated. Whenever it is generated as an SVG, it is ok, but when it is exported to a pdf, the text all shifts.

All of the  tags in the SVG file were set to x='0', y='0', as there were problems in the formatting of text. When the file is generated as an SVG file there are no problems at all. I'm not sure how the PDF drawings are generated, I am assuming that they are generated as SVGs and then exported but I don't know.

Here is an example of how the text has shifted, and how it looks in the SVG drawing:

[image]

[image]

Reproducible Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->
<svg height="793.33331" id="svg10" inkscape:version="0.92.3 (2405546, 2018-03-11)" sodipodi:docname="1c E37 Face Electric Operation No No.svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1122.6667 793.33331" width="1122.6667" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <metadata id="metadata16">
  <rdf:RDF>
   <cc:Work rdf:about="">
    <dc:format>
     image/svg+xml
    </dc:format>
    <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage"/>
    <dc:title/>
   </cc:Work>
  </rdf:RDF>
 </metadata>
 <sodipodi:namedview bordercolor="#666666" borderopacity="1" gridtolerance="10" guidetolerance="10" id="namedview12" inkscape:current-layer="g18" inkscape:cx="561.33337" inkscape:cy="396.66666" inkscape:pageopacity="0" inkscape:pageshadow="2" inkscape:window-height="2066" inkscape:window-maximized="1" inkscape:window-width="3840" inkscape:window-x="-11" inkscape:window-y="-11" inkscape:zoom="2.1646365" objecttolerance="10" pagecolor="#ffffff" showgrid="false"/>
 <g id="g18" inkscape:groupmode="layer" inkscape:label="1c E37 Face Electric Operation No No" transform="matrix(0,-0.08,-0.08,0,1120,790.66666)">
  <g id="g20">
   <g clip-path="url(#clipPath26)" id="g22"/>
  </g>
  <g id="g28">
   <g clip-path="url(#clipPath34)" id="g30"/>
  </g>
  <g id="g36">
   <g clip-path="url(#clipPath42)" id="g38"/>
  </g>
  <g id="g44">
   <g clip-path="url(#clipPath50)" id="g46"/>
  </g>
  <g>
    <path d="m 7819,5214 -204,-182 v -17" id="path16964" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"/>
    <path d="M 2874,6382 V 5212" id="path16966" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:12.5;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"/>
    <text id="text16970" style="font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:123.10199738px;font-family:Arial;-inkscape-font-specification:ArialMT;writing-mode:lr-tb;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" transform="matrix(0,-1,-1,0,2900,6382)">
     <tspan id="tspan16968" sodipodi:role="line" x="0" y="0">
      TYPICAL THROUGH
     </tspan>
    </text>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Post the SVG code...

Comment: @Scott see edit, the whole file is very large so I removed a lot of unnecessary parts

Comment: Well I see the problem but I don't know where it's being introduced. If I open the svg in Illustrator, the text has a bunch of empty spaced in front of it, causing the indent. A PDF, also being an Adobe format, I suspect is seeing the same thing. But I can't figure out *why* those spaces are being rendered.

Comment: Do you need any more of the code?

Comment: I'll have a look to see if it's anything to do with xml:space being preserved rather than default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I open the SVG in Illustrator, the text has a bunch of empty spaces before it. Since PDF is also an Adobe format, I suspect the PDF is seeing these same empty spaces.

After some playing.... just remove the white space in the SVG around the text...

`<tspan id="tspan16968" sodipodi:role="line" x="0" y="0">TYPICAL THROUGH</tspan>`

For some odd reason those line feeds, and the indent in the XML markup, are being seen as spaces and honored by Illustrator.